# Usinig SPI to create relationship with certain ENSO values

Tags: r, stack, raster, netcdf4

How can I use Standardized Precipitation Index (SPI) to create a relationship with ENSO values using a composite drought index (CDI)? I have generated the CDI and output it as JPEG, PDF, and PNG files. I now want to compile these outputs to detail varying degrees of drought levels in a format similar to the attached figure. What is the best way to manipulate these output files to achieve this? Any advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated.
[image]

I tried downloading the Chirps netcdf4 dataset from 1981 - 2023 but i cant convert that to SPI in order to link it to a ENSO value graph

Comment: This does not appear to be a coding question at this point. Maybe better try to ask this at [Earth Science](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/) and come back to StackOverflow when your idea is matured enough and you have specific implementation questions? Also, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example.